# what is the term "boh" stands for in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I found a job description says "BOH" in wordpress.
What is that?

> We are a small Web Design firm looking to add to our WP Dev team. The candidate must be proficient in WP BOH and be able to work quickly with a variety of themes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a job posting, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume it means "Back of House" - actually using WP in the admin backend?